# Numeric Derivative Frequency Response

Tags: spectrogram, highpass-filter, derivative

It seems quite common to use `np.diff()` for removing DC components of signals when plotting spectrograms.

I noticed some unexpected behaviour during analyis which indicated that a numeric derivative may amplify higher frequencies and I've been trying to check myself since.

So, I decided to treat the derivative as an FIR filter where `b = [1, -1]` and plot the frequency response to confirm my suspicions. Please excuse the plot, it's a work in progress.

[This post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/60970/frequency-response-of-numerical-derivative) seems to express the same problem, though OP is hardly surprised.

If some journeymen may weigh-in here and confirm/disprove my assumption.
I would use a notch filter centered at DC as an alternative, but any advice is welcome.

[image]

Comment: Actually that doesn't seem common to me at all. `np.diff()` is commonly used to approximate  a first order differentiator. The DC blocking is simply a side effect (the derivative of a DC signal is indeed zero). However DC blocking is normally done with real high pass filters that has a cutoff frequency below the frequency range of interest or simply by subtracting out the mean.

Comment: @Hilmar Thank you, I think this is a subtle error that has become commonplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, the first order difference in the time domain (`np.diff`) is equivalent to a first order high-pass filter with coefficients $h[0] = 1, h[1] = -1$ in the frequency domain. This filter then effectively removes the DC component, **which is the component with frequency 0, i.e the signal's average value**.

However, as you have rightly showed in your plot of the magnitude response, this filter isn't particularly satisfactory if one is interested in removing the DC component only: it attains unity gain only at about 1/3rd of Nyquist, and amplifies everything above that.

Common, better ways to remove DC before spectral analysis include:

- Removing the mean: `x = x - mean(x)`
- Use detrending functions: `x = detrend(x)`
- Use [DC blocking filters](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/fp/DC_Blocker.html)

---

**More detail**

To see why the first order difference is indeed a high-pass filter , consider the time-domain equation:
$$y[n] = x[n] - x[n-1]$$
In the frequency domain, the transfer function is:
$$H(z) = 1-z^{-1}$$
and the frequency response at $z = e^{j\omega}$:
$$H(\omega) = 1-e^{-j\omega}$$
From this, the magnitude response:
$$|H(\omega)| = |1-e^{-j\omega}| = |1-\cos(\omega) + j\sin(\omega)| = \sqrt{(1-\cos(\omega))^2 +\sin^2(\omega)} = \sqrt{2 - 2\cos(\omega)}$$

This is a high-pass filter:

- At $\omega = 0$, $|H(\omega)| = 0$
- At $\omega = \pi$, $|H(\omega)| = \sqrt{2}$
- Unity gain is achieved at $\sqrt{2 - 2\cos(\omega)} = 1 \leftrightarrow \omega = \pi/3$

Comment: Another way to write this $H(\omega) = -j\cdot \sin(\omega)\cdot  e^{-j\omega/2}$, which shows that for low frequency this behaves like an analog differentiator ($-j\omega$) cascaded with a half sample delay.

Comment: @Jdip Thanks so much for your input. That puts my self-doubt at ease.